# dplyr mutate, dynamic variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having difficulties with utilizing a dynamic variable in dplyr (specifically, using dply::mutate to pick out a specific column). It seems there are quite a few posts online about using dynamic variables in dplyr, but I've gotten confused by this. It seems the solution to use a dynamic variable, you need to write a function, then apply this to your dplyr pipe.

Is there a way to directly use a dynamic variable in a dplyr::mutate, either as a new column name and/or to reference a column that we want to apply the calculation to?

Below is an example (where I am trying to use two variables; newcol as the name of the new column I'm trying to create, and col as the name of the column I'm trying to apply the calculation to).

```
#libraries
library(dplyr)

#make dataframe and variables for name
testdf <- data.frame(cola=c(1,2,3),colb=c(4,5,6),colc=c(7,8,9))
col <- "cola"
newcol <- "newcolname"

#mutate: new column (with variable column name & variable column which I'm using to calculate)
testdf %>%
  dplyr::mutate(newcol=col*5)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As per the duplicate, `mutate(!!newcol := .data[[col]] * 5)` should work.

Comment: For a full treatment, see this article on [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).